# Graphics missing when deploying to azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, deployment

I just deployed my first MVC5 application to azure, and got everything to work, except that it is not showing graphics. On my development machine this works.

My graphics are in a folder `~/Content/Graphics`, and this is the part of the `_Layout.cshtml` that references one,

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/content/graphics/EluciusSoft_Logo.svg")" style="height:50px">
```

I know that the files are on the server, though, since I checked it with `WebMatrix`. Why are they not displaying?

EDIT: The browser console error message is the following:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

Here is a screenshot of the site directory using `WebMatrix`.

[image: Folder Screenshot]

Comment: Make sure you add your graphics to the actual solution and ensure they're added to your build (which you can do in the property "Copy to Output Directory" in the properties for each graphic).

Comment: Of course they are included in the project/solution. I have tried several build acions too, namely `Content` and `Embedded Resource`.

Comment: What errors do you get in browser console when you access a page that is meant to have graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the webserver hasn't been configured with the MIME type for SVG, then it will return a 404 error when you try and access it.  You can define the MIME type in your application's web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```